# Make sprite jump in cocos 2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am a total beginner to the cocos2d and i am stuccoed near a problem of making my sprite jump in vertical direction so please can anyone help me out of this situation...
here is my code...

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        // enable touches
        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        // enable accelerometer
        self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;

        ManStanding = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ManStanding.png"];
        [ManStanding setPosition:ccp(40,0)];
        [self addChild:ManStanding];
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    id jump = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1 position:ccp(100, 0)
                                   height:50 jumps:1];
    [ManStanding runAction:jump];
}
```

can anyone guide me what i am doing wrong..
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set 100 pixel jump in x-axis and 0 in y-axis. Try below code

```
    id jump_Up = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:1.0f position:ccp(0, 200)
                                    height:50 jumps:1];
    id jump_Down = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:0.7f position:ccp(0,-200)
                                    height:50 jumps:1];

    id seq = [CCSequence actions:jump_Up,jump_Down, nil];

    [sprite runAction:seq];
```

Comment: As i debugged i came to know that the event -(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event is not getting fired how can i resolve this..

Comment: try  - (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

Comment: if your cocos2d version 2.0 then use self.touchEnabled = YES; instead of self.isTouchEnabled

Answer (score 0):

```
id uppar = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:0.9f position:ccp(100,0) height:0 jumps:1];
id down = [CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:0.9f position:ccp(-100,0) height:0 jumps:1];
id seq = [CCSequence actions:uppar,down, nil];
[user1 runAction:seq];
```